# Keeping JMeter User Defined Variables and Uses DRY?

Tags: jmeter

I'm looking for a way to reuse User Defined Variables and Uses of said variables in a way that doesn't require repeating them in every JMeter test, I fear this isn't possible.

For example we've defined a few User Defined Variables (with more planned):

```
      <Arguments guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
    <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
      <elementProp name="SERVER" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">SERVER</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(server,localhost)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
      <elementProp name="PORT" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">PORT</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(port,80)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
      <elementProp name="PATH" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">PATH</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(path,)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
      <elementProp name="LOOPS" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">LOOPS</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(loops,1)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
      <elementProp name="THREADS" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">THREADS</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(threads,1)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
      <elementProp name="RAMPSECONDS" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">RAMPSECONDS</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(rampseconds,1)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
      <elementProp name="USERPREFIX" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">USERPREFIX</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(userprefix,testuser)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
      <elementProp name="COUNTERCONFIGSTART" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">COUNTERCONFIGSTART</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(counterconfigstart,1)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
      <elementProp name="COUNTERCONFIGEND" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">COUNTERCONFIGEND</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(counterconfigend,6)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
      <elementProp name="COUNTERCONFIGINCR" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">COUNTERCONFIGINCR</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(counterconfigincr,1)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
    </collectionProp>
  </Arguments>
```

And then use them:

```
  <ConfigTestElement guiclass="HttpDefaultsGui" testclass="ConfigTestElement" testname="HTTP Request Defaults" enabled="true">
    <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
      <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
    </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">${SERVER}</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">${PORT}</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">${PATH}</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.concurrentPool">4</stringProp>
  </ConfigTestElement>
  ....
  <CounterConfig guiclass="CounterConfigGui" testclass="CounterConfig" testname="USER Counter" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="CounterConfig.start">${COUNTERCONFIGSTART}</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="CounterConfig.end">${COUNTERCONFIGEND}</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="CounterConfig.incr">${COUNTERCONFIGINCR}</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="CounterConfig.name">USER</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="CounterConfig.format">${USERPREFIX}</stringProp>
    <boolProp name="CounterConfig.per_user">false</boolProp>
  </CounterConfig>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up extracting the last few differences in our JMeter tests to User Defined Variables and then defined the variables in a csv file and used the [JMeter's CSV Data Set](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

However, when running on Jenkins the test results are then in 1 log file and hence 1 graph, which isn't what we want.  We want 1 graph per page under test.  So I used Freemarker to generate separate tests one for each line in the csv file.  Since JMeter and Freemarker use the same variable notation ( ${myvariable} ) I replaced all the JMeter ${ with @{ which are then replaced after the Freemarker templating is done.